# Automatically put a menu on every post

Tags: plugins, posts, menus

I want to **automatically** put a menu on every post (Contact Form requesting DMCA Takedown, Contact Form requesting change of category or tag, etc.).

Any ideas on a plug-in that will do this? Searching for this led me to all kinds of links to add posts to menus ... but not menus to posts!

Thanks very much,

John

Comment: You want to change the menu in the header or add the special menu on the content of the post ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing where exactly you want to put this (all posts, certain categories, etc.) I will give you the way to do it across the board.

First step is to go into `functions.php` and find the function where your menus are being defined. Inside that function add the following code:

```
register_nav_menu( 'dmca', __( 'DMCA', 'theme-slug' ) );
```

NOTE: Replace `theme-slug` with whatever the `textdomain` is in your `style.css` file.

This will add a new menu named "DMCA" that you can then fill with whatever options you want.

Then, in your `single.php` file, add the following code in the location where you want the menu to appear:

```
wp_nav_menu( 
   array(
      'theme_location' => 'dmca',
   )
 );
```

This will place the menu you defined earlier in this location. I suggest looking at the developer resource WordPress has for [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) as it has many more options you can put in that array such as adding classes, id, etc. to it as well.

Comment: Thanks @Cedon. I'm a WordPress newbie ... so your response is **way** above my level of knowledge!

Thanks again,

John

Comment: You can actually just cut and paste that code. If you have your theme on Github I can help you with it on there too.